# SSMS: Total invoice count from total vendors per property

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I'm not a SQL expert, my query for pulling invoice count from "building properties" should throughput the total number of invoices with total vendors per property. I have tried the following query, can you suggest something with a similar result?

[Script Query]

```
SELECT property, count(distinct InvoiceNo) as Total Number of Invoices 
From dbo.Invoices
Where tstamp >= '2020-01-01'
Group By InvoiceNo;
```

Desired Output Data

```
   Total Number of Invoices | Frequently Used Vendors |  Property
   200                      | Name of Vendor          |  Property Name
```

Comment: The easiest way to test if a query works is to run it. The fact, therefore, you are posting this question suggests that it *isn't* working. You say that the above it "dynamic" as well, but it's not. A `VIEW` can't be dynamic. Also, why use `DISTINCT`? Do you have duplicate rows in your table `Invoices`? Is so, that's a problem you certainly want to fix.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. There is nothing *dynamic* with your current query, which makes your question quite unclear.

Comment: @LArnu - after running stored query I get the following error:  Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vw_Invoices, Line 25
Invalid object name 'dbo.Invoices'.
Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Could not use view or function 'dbo.Invoices' because of binding errors.

Comment: @GMB - currently not able to add sample data. I will revise and improve the post if that is accessible.

Comment: @LArnu - updated my question.

Comment: @GMB -  Updated query.

Comment: Is the error you're getting still *"Invalid object name 'dbo.Invoices'"*? If so, the error is telling you the problem here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the top vendor per property. If so, you can do:

```
select *
from (
    select property, vendor, count(*) cnt_invoices,
        rank() over(partition by property order by count(*) desc) rn 
    from dbo.invoices
    where tstamp >= '2020-01-01'
    group by property, vendor
) t
where rn = 1
order by property
```

This allows top ties, if any. You can get the same result using `with ties` and `order by`:

```
select top (1) with ties property, vendor, count(*) cnt_invoices
from dbo.invoices
where tstamp >= '2020-01-01'
group by property, vendor
order by rank() over(partition by property order by count(*) desc)
```

Comment: I tried your first query posted and it works okay with one concern. When I try to do a UNION ALL for selecting a second server, I get the following error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.   ?What Could be wrong?

Comment: @hmm4089: your question does not mention anything about a *second server*, so I just don't know what you mean. My answer addresses the question that you asked. If you have another question, then you should ask it as *a new question*, providing the proper context, sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thank you, both your answers truly work. Regarding server Union ALL questions, I will post my second question as new question.